# Is xpath.useNamespaces thread safe?

Tags: node.js, xpath

Trying to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/xpath

```
var xpath = require('xpath');

var xpath_select = xpath.useNamespaces({
    "my": "http://my.com/core/api"
});

module.exports.handler = function (request, context, callback) {
    ...
    xpath_select(...)
    ...
};
```

Should I move xpath_select initialization to handler function or I can initialize it once at startup?

I am aware of multi-threading issues.

Comment: node is single threaded. There's no thread safety issue

Comment: @slebetman Do you mean that several simultaneous requests will be handled one by one and not in parallel ?

Comment: Yes. In node no code run in parallel since it is single threaded (you can of course use clustering which is multi process or you can use libraries which implement web workers which is multi threaded but most of them use a message passing model where the threads and the main process don't share memory). How node handle parallel requests is that it WAITS in parallel. That's what async IO / nonblocking IO / evented / concurrent programming (it has many names) is all about. There is a saying, concurrent != parallel.

Comment: There used to be actual pthreads libraries written for node (written in C of course) way back in 2012. But I've not seen anyone use them since. Paradoxically with high throughput network servers threading can slow down your program (often caused by locks). The reason node is still popular in 2017 after more than 5 years of criticism by people who thought it's singlethreaded nature was stupid is because it has held up its performance promise. My company for example have switched our Java servers from multithreaded to singlethreaded for the same reason (using play framework)

Comment: See my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855352/how-in-general-does-node-js-handle-10-000-concurrent-requests/34857298#34857298