# Traffic all of restful api Process

Tags: api, server, cloud

I want to know if there's many people request URL on a port (**exam. 7000**) it will handle on a request in  a order, right?

And  connect to a database through my API server.

So the client post to my API server through URL: Port and then my API sever connect my database and then return data to client though API server by response `JSON` Format and next it gonna continue do the same right?

So if it’s in a process others request has to wait until it finish a process that I mention above, right?

Comment: It's depends on which platform you are working on. Please mention the language you have been using eg. Java, node.js etc.

Comment: Node.js and use postgreSql

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer

> No

Server will not wait for the database operation to complete and therefore keep accepting the other request.

The flow of execution will be as follow:

```
request ──> make database request
request ──> make database request
request ──> make database request
database request complete ──> send response
database request complete ──> send response
database request complete ──> send response
```

[Read this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34855352/how-in-general-does-node-js-handle-10-000-concurrent-requests) for precise and simple explanation.

This is possible because of following concepts and I recommend you to read about it more to understand how Node.js works

1. [Event Loop](https://youtu.be/8aGhZQkoFbQ)
2. [Asynchronous Nature of Node.js](https://blog.risingstack.com/node-hero-async-programming-in-node-js/)
3. Node.js internally use [libuv](https://github.com/libuv/libuv) to handle I/O operation.