# How does Javascript handle obsolete callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, event-loop

I'm trying to understand the event loop in Node JS. There are fantastic resources online but i keep finding myself wondering the same thing. The scenario is below:

For Javascript/Node
On a web page with a getData button.
The user clicks the button and a request is sent to the server to the getData route (in this simplified scenario when the server gets the data it returns a new page showing the data). The data request is asynchronously offloaded to a Node API (and out of the call stack).
Before the api returns the data the user changes pages in the browser, a new http request is sent to the server for a different page and this fires an http.get(url, callback) adding the new page to the callback queue to be loaded (this beats the data request and the new page is returned).

What happens to the old callback for the now redundant data? Presumably when the event loop reaches the getData callback in the cb queue, it will attempt to run the callback function. Will Node send a response to change the page again with the data displaying page? If it was Ajax and the data returned after a page change what happens to the callback in this scenario, does ajax simply ignore the returned data on the new, different page?

I know Ajax handles on page updates but i wanted to simplify to understand how the event loop handles situation where the call stack has moved on and the older callbacks are no longer useful.

Thankyou for the responses they have been very useful! The only thing that i would add is (and i understand this scenario requires very bad server design but the theory is my interest here) if the server does respond with a page that is no longer wanted by the user (due to the delay in async response), does the browser understand that this is not the most recent request? I think as http is stateless the browser will receive the response over TCP and reload with the previously requested page (to the the clients frustration).

Many thanks!

Comment: Node.js isn't running in your browser.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Node js, what happens if a new request arrives and event loop is already busy processing a request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60694389/in-node-js-what-happens-if-a-new-request-arrives-and-event-loop-is-already-busy)

Comment: its close @BraveButter thank you, but it doesn't quite answer what happens to the callback when it no longer has a purpose.

Answer (score 0):

In a simplified HTTP request scenario, a connection is established between client (eg Web browser) and server first, using TCP.

HTTP is sent over this link to configure the exchange of data.

The TCP connection is maintained until either end closes it (usually client says "Thanks! All done!"). So the TCP connection remains open while the Node.js process fetches some data asynchronously.

If a user gives up waiting for a response and (say) closes the browser, then the TCP connection is closed on both ends. Meanwhile, the callback for the database call continues to exist in server memory, ready for when the DB returns. The DB then returns, the callback is run, and as soon as the callback attempts to send data back to the client over the TCP connection it will discover it has been closed and a suitable error will be raised (and possibly caught) on the server-side.

The callback then exits, the stack frame is popped off the stack, the memory allocated to the stack frame is freed, and control returns to the previous frame. When the garbage collector in the Node.js JavaScript runtime next runs, any objects solely linked to that no-longer-in-existence frame are swept up and the memory associated with them is freed.

In an unhappy-path scenario (eg. power plug pulled on the client computer), then the server will think the TCP connection is still open for a configurable period, until it times out, or it discovers it is unable to successfully send data across it, at which point the server closes it and cleans up the associated memory.

This can be complicated by the concept of [HTTP keep-alive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection), which involves the browser and server agreeing to use a single TCP connection for multiple HTTP requests to save time. Under HTTP keep-alive, the HTTP protocol is leveraged to ensure the browser will safely ignore any data returned over the TCP connection that corresponds to a no-longer active request.

And there is an even more modern technique of multiplexing several concurrent HTTP requests over the same TCP connection too, but that is outside the scope of this question.

I think.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure the browser discards the response because the request itself is closed.  It depends on the timing, the server (forget whether it's node.js or apache or anything else) might still get the response in time to try to respond to it.  If it does respond to it, it doesn't care what the browser does with the response.

You say

> The user clicks the button and a request is sent to the server to the getData route (in this simplified scenario when the server gets the data it returns a new page showing the data). The data request is asynchronously offloaded to a Node API (and out of the call stack)

The browser is oblivious of the server's implementation.  It doesn't care how the server responds as long as it tries to respond.  At the same time, the server is also oblivious of the "state" of the browser.  All the server knows is that there is an open request that it needs to respond to and does so.  Once it has responded, it doesn't care.

> I know Ajax handles on page updates but i wanted to simplify to understand how the event loop handles situation where the call stack has moved on and the older callbacks are no longer useful.

There is no movement of the callstack, the server received a request and as long as that request is open, the server should respond to it.  If **another** request comes in (even if the new request is nearly identical) the server will also respond to that request separately.