# Server crashing while being interrupted sending large chunk of data

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, boost-asio

My server crashes when I gracefully close a client that is connected to it, while the client is receiving a large chunk of data. I am thinking of a possible lifetime bug as with the most bugs in boost ASIO, however I was not able to point out my mistake myself.

Each client establishes 2 connection with the server, one of them is for syncing, the other connection is long-lived one to receive continuous updates. In the "syncing phase" client receives large data to sync with the server state ("state" is basically DB data in JSON format). After syncing, sync connection is closed. Client receives updates to the DB as it happens (these are of course very small data compared to "syncing data") via the other connection.

These are the relevant files:

connection.h

```
#pragma once

#include <array>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

class ConnectionManager;

/// Represents a single connection from a client.
class Connection : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Connection>
{
public:
  Connection(const Connection&) = delete;
  Connection& operator=(const Connection&) = delete;

  /// Construct a connection with the given socket.
  explicit Connection(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket, ConnectionManager& manager);

  /// Start the first asynchronous operation for the connection.
  void start();

  /// Stop all asynchronous operations associated with the connection.
  void stop();

  /// Perform an asynchronous write operation.
  void do_write(const std::string& buffer);

  int getNativeHandle();

  ~Connection();

private:
  /// Perform an asynchronous read operation.
  void do_read();

  /// Socket for the connection.
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_;

  /// The manager for this connection.
  ConnectionManager& connection_manager_;

  /// Buffer for incoming data.
  std::array<char, 8192> buffer_;

  std::string outgoing_buffer_;
};

typedef std::shared_ptr<Connection> connection_ptr;
```

connection.cpp

```
#include "connection.h"

#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>

#include "connection_manager.h"

Connection::Connection(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket, ConnectionManager& manager)
    : socket_(std::move(socket))
    , connection_manager_(manager)
{
}

void Connection::start()
{
  do_read();
}

void Connection::stop()
{
  socket_.close();
}

Connection::~Connection()
{
}

void Connection::do_read()
{
  auto self(shared_from_this());
  socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(buffer_), [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
        if (!ec) {
            std::string buff_str = std::string(buffer_.data(), bytes_transferred);
            const auto& tokenized_buffer = split(buff_str, ' ');
            
            if(!tokenized_buffer.empty() && tokenized_buffer[0] == "sync") {
                /// "syncing connection" sends a specific text
                /// hence I can separate between sycing and long-lived connections here and act accordingly.

                const auto& exec_json_strs = getExecutionJsons();
                const auto& order_json_strs = getOrdersAsJsons();
                const auto& position_json_strs = getPositionsAsJsons();
                const auto& all_json_strs = exec_json_strs + order_json_strs + position_json_strs + createSyncDoneJson();
                
                /// this is potentially a very large data.
                do_write(all_json_strs);
            }

            do_read();
        } else {
          connection_manager_.stop(shared_from_this());
        }
      });
}

void Connection::do_write(const std::string& write_buffer)
{
  outgoing_buffer_ = write_buffer;

  auto self(shared_from_this());
  boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(outgoing_buffer_, outgoing_buffer_.size()), [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t transfer_size) {
        if (!ec) {
           /// everything is fine.
        } else {
           /// what to do here?
           /// server crashes once I get error code 32 (EPIPE) here.
        }
      });
}
```

connection_manager.h

```
#pragma once

#include <set>
#include "connection.h"

/// Manages open connections so that they may be cleanly stopped when the server
/// needs to shut down.
class ConnectionManager
{
public:
  ConnectionManager(const ConnectionManager&) = delete;
  ConnectionManager& operator=(const ConnectionManager&) = delete;

  /// Construct a connection manager.
  ConnectionManager();

  /// Add the specified connection to the manager and start it.
  void start(connection_ptr c);

  /// Stop the specified connection.
  void stop(connection_ptr c);

  /// Stop all connections.
  void stop_all();

  void sendAllConnections(const std::string& buffer);

private:
  /// The managed connections.
  std::set<connection_ptr> connections_;
};
```

connection_manager.cpp

```
#include "connection_manager.h"

ConnectionManager::ConnectionManager()
{
}

void ConnectionManager::start(connection_ptr c)
{
  connections_.insert(c);
  c->start();
}

void ConnectionManager::stop(connection_ptr c)
{
    connections_.erase(c);
    c->stop();
}

void ConnectionManager::stop_all()
{
  for (auto c: connections_)
    c->stop();

  connections_.clear();
}

/// this function is used to keep clients up to date with the changes, not used during syncing phase.
void ConnectionManager::sendAllConnections(const std::string& buffer)
{
  for (auto c: connections_)
      c->do_write(buffer);
}
```

server.h

```
#pragma once

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <string>
#include "connection.h"
#include "connection_manager.h"

class Server
{
public:
  Server(const Server&) = delete;
  Server& operator=(const Server&) = delete;

  /// Construct the server to listen on the specified TCP address and port, and
  /// serve up files from the given directory.
  explicit Server(const std::string& address, const std::string& port);

  /// Run the server's io_service loop.
  void run();

  void deliver(const std::string& buffer);

private:
  /// Perform an asynchronous accept operation.
  void do_accept();

  /// Wait for a request to stop the server.
  void do_await_stop();

  /// The io_service used to perform asynchronous operations.
  boost::asio::io_service io_service_;

  /// The signal_set is used to register for process termination notifications.
  boost::asio::signal_set signals_;

  /// Acceptor used to listen for incoming connections.
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor_;

  /// The connection manager which owns all live connections.
  ConnectionManager connection_manager_;

  /// The *NEXT* socket to be accepted.
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_;
};
```

server.cpp

```
#include "server.h"
#include <signal.h>
#include <utility>

Server::Server(const std::string& address, const std::string& port)
    : io_service_()
    , signals_(io_service_)
    , acceptor_(io_service_)
    , connection_manager_()
    , socket_(io_service_)
{
  // Register to handle the signals that indicate when the server should exit.
  // It is safe to register for the same signal multiple times in a program,
  // provided all registration for the specified signal is made through Asio.
  signals_.add(SIGINT);
  signals_.add(SIGTERM);
#if defined(SIGQUIT)
  signals_.add(SIGQUIT);
#endif // defined(SIGQUIT)

  do_await_stop();

  // Open the acceptor with the option to reuse the address (i.e. SO_REUSEADDR).
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(io_service_);
  boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = *resolver.resolve({address, port});
  acceptor_.open(endpoint.protocol());
  acceptor_.set_option(boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
  acceptor_.bind(endpoint);
  acceptor_.listen();

  do_accept();
}

void Server::run()
{
  // The io_service::run() call will block until all asynchronous operations
  // have finished. While the server is running, there is always at least one
  // asynchronous operation outstanding: the asynchronous accept call waiting
  // for new incoming connections.
  io_service_.run();
}

void Server::do_accept()
{
  acceptor_.async_accept(socket_,
      [this](boost::system::error_code ec)
      {
        // Check whether the server was stopped by a signal before this
        // completion handler had a chance to run.
        if (!acceptor_.is_open())
        {
          return;
        }

        if (!ec)
        {
          connection_manager_.start(std::make_shared<Connection>(
              std::move(socket_), connection_manager_));
        }

        do_accept();
      });
}

void Server::do_await_stop()
{
  signals_.async_wait(
      [this](boost::system::error_code /*ec*/, int /*signo*/)
      {
        // The server is stopped by cancelling all outstanding asynchronous
        // operations. Once all operations have finished the io_service::run()
        // call will exit.
        acceptor_.close();
        connection_manager_.stop_all();
      });
}

/// this function is used to keep clients up to date with the changes, not used during syncing phase.
void Server::deliver(const std::string& buffer)
{
    connection_manager_.sendAllConnections(buffer);
}
```

So, I am repeating my question: My server crashes when I gracefully close a client that is connected to it, while the client is receiving a large chunk of data and I do not know why.

Edit: Crash happens in async_write function, as soon as I receive EPIPE error. The application is multithreaded. There are 4 threads that call Server::deliver with their own data as it is produced. deliver() is used for keeping clients up to date, it has nothing to do with the initial syncing: syncing is done with persistent data fetched from db.

I had a single io_service, so I thought that I would not need strands. io_service::run is called on main thread, so the main thread is blocking.

Comment: I recommend adding to the question where the crash occurs. This probably won't be where the mistake is, but it often tells you a lot about what happened to cause the crash.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reviewing, adding some missing code bits:

```
namespace /*missing code stubs*/ {
    auto split(std::string_view input, char delim) {
        std::vector<std::string_view> result;
        boost::algorithm::split(result, input,
                                boost::algorithm::is_from_range(delim, delim));
        return result;
    }

    std::string getExecutionJsons()   { return ""; }
    std::string getOrdersAsJsons()    { return ""; }
    std::string getPositionsAsJsons() { return ""; }
    std::string createSyncDoneJson()  { return ""; }
}
```

Now the things I notice are:

1. you have a single `io_service`, so a single thread. Okay, so no strands should be required unless you have threads in your other code (`main`, e.g.?).
2. A particular reason to suspect that threads are at play is that nobody could possibly call `Server::deliver` because `run()` is blocking. This means that whenever you call `deliver()` now it causes a data race, which leads to [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)

   The casual comment

   ```
    /// this function is used to keep clients up to date with the changes,
    /// not used during syncing phase.
   ```

   does not do much to remove this concern. The code needs to defend against misuse. Comments do not get executed. Make it better:

   ```
    void Server::deliver(const std::string& buffer) {
        post(io_context_,
             [this, buffer] { connection_manager_.broadcast(std::move(buffer)); });
    }
   ```
3. you do not check that previous writes are completed before accepting a "new" one. This means that calling `Connection::do_write` results in [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) for two reasons:

   - modifying `outgoing_buffer_` during an ongoing async operation that uses that buffer is UB
   - having two overlapped `async_write` on the same IO object is UB (see [docs](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_78_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/async_write/overload1.html#:%7E:text=This%20operation%20is,this%20operation%20complete)

   The typical way to fix that is to have a queue of outgoing messages instead.
4. using `async_read_some` is rarely what you want, especially since the reads don't accumulate into a dynamic buffer. This means that if your packets get separated at unexpected boundaries, you may not detect commands at all, or incorrectly.

   Instead consider `asio::async_read_until` with a dynamic buffer (e.g.

   - read directly into `std::string` so you don't have to copy the buffer into a string
   - read into `streambuf` so you can use `std::istream(&sbuf_)` to parse instead of tokenizing
5. Concatenating `all_json_strs` which clearly *have* to be owning text containers is wasteful. Instead, use a const-buffer-sequence to combine them all without copying.

   Better yet, consider a streaming approach to JSON serialization so not all the JSON needs to be serialized in memory at any given time.
6. Don't declare empty destructors (`~Connection`). They're pessimizations
7. Likewise for empty constructors (`ConnectionManager`). If you must, consider

   ```
   ConnectionManager::ConnectionManager() = default;
   ```
8. The `getNativeHandle` gives me more questions about other code that may interfere. E.g. it may indicate other libraries doing operations, which again can lead to overlapped reads/writes, or it could be a sign of more code living on threads (as `Server::run()` is by definition blocking)
9. Connection manager should probably hold `weak_ptr`, so `Connection`s could eventually terminate. Now, the last reference is **by defintion** held in the connection manager, meaning nothing ever gets destructed when the peer disconnects or the session fails for some other reason.
10. This is not idiomatic:

    ```
    // Check whether the server was stopped by a signal before this
    // completion handler had a chance to run.
    if (!acceptor_.is_open()) {
        return;
    }
    ```

    If you closed the acceptor, the completion handler is called with `error::operation_aborted` anyways. Simply handle that, e.g. in the final version I'll post later:

    ```
    // separate strand for each connection - just in case you ever add threads
    acceptor_.async_accept(
        make_strand(io_context_), [this](error_code ec, tcp::socket sock) {
            if (!ec) {
                connection_manager_.register_and_start(
                    std::make_shared<Connection>(std::move(sock),
                                                 connection_manager_));
                do_accept();
            }
        });
    ```
11. I notice this comment:

    ```
    // The server is stopped by cancelling all outstanding asynchronous
    // operations. Once all operations have finished the io_service::run()
    // call will exit.
    ```

    In fact you never `cancel()` any operation on any IO object in your code. Again, comments aren't executed. It's better to indeed do as you say, and let the destructors close the resources. This prevents spurious errors when objects are used-after-close, and also prevents very annoying race conditions when e.g. you closed the handle, some other thread re-opened a new stream on the same filedescriptor and you had given out the handle to a third party (using `getNativeHandle`)... you see where this leads?

### Reproducing The Problem?

Having reviewed this way, I tried to repro the issue, so I created fake data:

```
    std::string getExecutionJsons()   { return std::string(1024,  'E'); }
    std::string getOrdersAsJsons()    { return std::string(13312, 'O'); }
    std::string getPositionsAsJsons() { return std::string(8192,  'P'); }
    std::string createSyncDoneJson()  { return std::string(24576, 'C'); }
```

With some minor tweaks to the Connection class:

```
    std::string buff_str =
        std::string(buffer_.data(), bytes_transferred);
    const auto& tokenized_buffer = split(buff_str, ' ');

    if (!tokenized_buffer.empty() &&
        tokenized_buffer[0] == "sync") {
        std::cerr << "sync detected on " << socket_.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;
        /// "syncing connection" sends a specific text
        /// hence I can separate between sycing and long-lived
        /// connections here and act accordingly.

        const auto& exec_json_strs     = getExecutionJsons();
        const auto& order_json_strs    = getOrdersAsJsons();
        const auto& position_json_strs = getPositionsAsJsons();
        const auto& all_json_strs      = exec_json_strs +
            order_json_strs + position_json_strs +
            createSyncDoneJson();

        std::cerr << "All json length: " << all_json_strs.length() << std::endl;
        /// this is potentially a very large data.
        do_write(all_json_strs); // already on strand!
    }
```

We get the server outputting

```
sync detected on 127.0.0.1:43012
All json length: 47104
sync detected on 127.0.0.1:43044
All json length: 47104
```

And clients faked with netcat:

```
$ netcat localhost 8989 <<< 'sync me' > expected
^C
$ wc -c expected 
47104 expected
```

Good. Now let's cause premature disconnect:

```
netcat localhost 8989 -w0 <<< 'sync me' > truncated
$ wc -c truncated 
0 truncated
```

So, it does lead to early close, but server still says

```
sync detected on 127.0.0.1:44176
All json length: 47104
```

Let's instrument `do_write` as well:

```
    async_write( //
        socket_, boost::asio::buffer(outgoing_buffer_, outgoing_buffer_.size()),
        [/*this,*/ self](error_code ec, size_t transfer_size) {
            std::cerr << "do_write completion: " << transfer_size << " bytes ("
                      << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;

            if (!ec) {
                /// everything is fine.
            } else {
                /// what to do here?
                // FIXME: probably cancel the read loop so the connection
                // closes?
            }
        });
```

Now we see:

```
sync detected on 127.0.0.1:44494
All json length: 47104
do_write completion: 47104 bytes (Success)
sync detected on 127.0.0.1:44512
All json length: 47104
do_write completion: 32768 bytes (Operation canceled)
```

For one disconnected and one "okay" connection.

No sign of crashes/undefined behaviour. Let's check with `-fsanitize=address,undefined`: clean record, even adding a heartbeat:

```
int main() {
    Server s("127.0.0.1", "8989");

    std::thread yolo([&s] {
        using namespace std::literals;
        int i = 1;

        do {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s);
        } while (s.deliver("HEARTBEAT DEMO " + std::to_string(i++)));
    });

    s.run();

    yolo.join();
}
```

### Conclusion

The only problem highlighted above that weren't addressed were:

- additional threading issues not shown (perhaps via `getNativeHandle`)
- the fact that you can have overlapping writes in the Connection `do_write`. Fixing that:

  ```
   void Connection::write(std::string msg) { // public, might not be on the strand
       post(socket_.get_executor(),
            [self = shared_from_this(), msg = std::move(msg)]() mutable {
                self->do_write(std::move(msg));
            });
   }

   void Connection::do_write(std::string msg) { // assumed on the strand
       outgoing_.push_back(std::move(msg));

       if (outgoing_.size() == 1)
           do_write_loop();
   }

   void Connection::do_write_loop() {
       if (outgoing_.size() == 0)
           return;

       auto self(shared_from_this());
       async_write( //
           socket_, boost::asio::buffer(outgoing_.front()),
           [this, self](error_code ec, size_t transfer_size) {
               std::cerr << "write completion: " << transfer_size << " bytes ("
                         << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;

               if (!ec) {
                   outgoing_.pop_front();
                   do_write_loop();
               } else {
                   socket_.cancel();

                   // This would ideally be enough to free the connection, but
                   // since `ConnectionManager` doesn't use `weak_ptr` you need to
                   // force the issue using kind of an "umbillical cord reflux":
                   connection_manager_.stop(self);
               }
           });
   }
  ```

As you can see I also split `write`/`do_write` to prevent off-strand invocation. Same with `stop`.

### Full Listing

A full listing with all the remarks/fixes from above:

- File `connection.h`

  ```
   #pragma once

   #include <boost/asio.hpp>

   #include <array>
   #include <deque>
   #include <memory>
   #include <string>
   using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

   class ConnectionManager;

   /// Represents a single connection from a client.
   class Connection : public std::enable_shared_from_this<Connection> {
     public:
       Connection(const Connection&) = delete;
       Connection& operator=(const Connection&) = delete;

       /// Construct a connection with the given socket.
       explicit Connection(tcp::socket socket, ConnectionManager& manager);

       void start();
       void stop();
       void write(std::string msg);

     private:
       void do_stop();
       void do_write(std::string msg);
       void do_write_loop();

       /// Perform an asynchronous read operation.
       void do_read();

       /// Socket for the connection.
       tcp::socket socket_;

       /// The manager for this connection.
       ConnectionManager& connection_manager_;

       /// Buffer for incoming data.
       std::array<char, 8192> buffer_;

       std::deque<std::string> outgoing_;
   };

   using connection_ptr = std::shared_ptr<Connection>;
  ```
- File `connection_manager.h`

  ```
   #pragma once

   #include <list>
   #include "connection.h"

   /// Manages open connections so that they may be cleanly stopped when the server
   /// needs to shut down.
   class ConnectionManager {
     public:
       ConnectionManager(const ConnectionManager&) = delete;
       ConnectionManager& operator=(const ConnectionManager&) = delete;
       ConnectionManager() = default; // could be split across h/cpp if you wanted

       void register_and_start(connection_ptr c);
       void stop(connection_ptr c);
       void stop_all();

       void broadcast(const std::string& buffer);

       // purge defunct connections, returns remaining active connections
       size_t garbage_collect();

     private:
       using handle = std::weak_ptr<connection_ptr::element_type>;
       std::list<handle> connections_;
   };
  ```
- File `server.h`

  ```
   #pragma once

   #include <boost/asio.hpp>
   #include <string>
   #include "connection.h"
   #include "connection_manager.h"

   class Server {
     public:
       Server(const Server&) = delete;
       Server& operator=(const Server&) = delete;

       /// Construct the server to listen on the specified TCP address and port,
       /// and serve up files from the given directory.
       explicit Server(const std::string& address, const std::string& port);

       /// Run the server's io_service loop.
       void run();

       bool deliver(const std::string& buffer);

     private:
       void do_accept();
       void do_await_signal();

       boost::asio::io_context      io_context_;
       boost::asio::any_io_executor strand_{io_context_.get_executor()};
       boost::asio::signal_set      signals_{strand_};
       tcp::acceptor                acceptor_{strand_};
       ConnectionManager            connection_manager_;
   };
  ```
- File `connection.cpp`

  ```
   #include "connection.h"

   #include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
   #include <iostream>
   #include <thread>
   #include <utility>
   #include <vector>

   #include "connection_manager.h"
   using boost::system::error_code;

   Connection::Connection(tcp::socket socket, ConnectionManager& manager)
       : socket_(std::move(socket))
       , connection_manager_(manager) {}

   void Connection::start() { // always assumed on the strand (since connection
                              // just constructed)
       do_read();
   }

   void Connection::stop() { // public, might not be on the strand
       post(socket_.get_executor(),
            [self = shared_from_this()]() mutable {
                self->do_stop();
            });
   }

   void Connection::do_stop() { // assumed on the strand
       socket_.cancel(); // trust shared pointer to destruct
   }

   namespace /*missing code stubs*/ {
       auto split(std::string_view input, char delim) {
           std::vector<std::string_view> result;
           boost::algorithm::split(result, input,
                                   boost::algorithm::is_from_range(delim, delim));
           return result;
       }

       std::string getExecutionJsons()   { return std::string(1024,  'E'); }
       std::string getOrdersAsJsons()    { return std::string(13312, 'O'); }
       std::string getPositionsAsJsons() { return std::string(8192,  'P'); }
       std::string createSyncDoneJson()  { return std::string(24576, 'C'); }
   } // namespace

   void Connection::do_read() {
       auto self(shared_from_this());
       socket_.async_read_some(
           boost::asio::buffer(buffer_),
           [this, self](error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred) {
               if (!ec) {
                   std::string buff_str =
                       std::string(buffer_.data(), bytes_transferred);
                   const auto& tokenized_buffer = split(buff_str, ' ');

                   if (!tokenized_buffer.empty() &&
                       tokenized_buffer[0] == "sync") {
                       std::cerr << "sync detected on " << socket_.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;
                       /// "syncing connection" sends a specific text
                       /// hence I can separate between sycing and long-lived
                       /// connections here and act accordingly.

                       const auto& exec_json_strs     = getExecutionJsons();
                       const auto& order_json_strs    = getOrdersAsJsons();
                       const auto& position_json_strs = getPositionsAsJsons();
                       const auto& all_json_strs      = exec_json_strs +
                           order_json_strs + position_json_strs +
                           createSyncDoneJson();

                       std::cerr << "All json length: " << all_json_strs.length() << std::endl;
                       /// this is potentially a very large data.
                       do_write(all_json_strs); // already on strand!
                   }

                   do_read();
               } else {
                   std::cerr << "do_read terminating: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
                   connection_manager_.stop(shared_from_this());
               }
           });
   }

   void Connection::write(std::string msg) { // public, might not be on the strand
       post(socket_.get_executor(),
            [self = shared_from_this(), msg = std::move(msg)]() mutable {
                self->do_write(std::move(msg));
            });
   }

   void Connection::do_write(std::string msg) { // assumed on the strand
       outgoing_.push_back(std::move(msg));

       if (outgoing_.size() == 1)
           do_write_loop();
   }

   void Connection::do_write_loop() {
       if (outgoing_.size() == 0)
           return;

       auto self(shared_from_this());
       async_write( //
           socket_, boost::asio::buffer(outgoing_.front()),
           [this, self](error_code ec, size_t transfer_size) {
               std::cerr << "write completion: " << transfer_size << " bytes ("
                         << ec.message() << ")" << std::endl;

               if (!ec) {
                   outgoing_.pop_front();
                   do_write_loop();
               } else {
                   socket_.cancel();

                   // This would ideally be enough to free the connection, but
                   // since `ConnectionManager` doesn't use `weak_ptr` you need to
                   // force the issue using kind of an "umbellical cord reflux":
                   connection_manager_.stop(self);
               }
           });
   }
  ```
- File `connection_manager.cpp`

  ```
   #include "connection_manager.h"

   void ConnectionManager::register_and_start(connection_ptr c) {
       connections_.emplace_back(c);
       c->start();
   }

   void ConnectionManager::stop(connection_ptr c) {
       c->stop();
   }

   void ConnectionManager::stop_all() {
       for (auto h : connections_)
           if (auto c = h.lock())
               c->stop();
   }

   /// this function is used to keep clients up to date with the changes, not used
   /// during syncing phase.
   void ConnectionManager::broadcast(const std::string& buffer) {
       for (auto h : connections_)
           if (auto c = h.lock())
               c->write(buffer);
   }

   size_t ConnectionManager::garbage_collect() {
       connections_.remove_if(std::mem_fn(&handle::expired));
       return connections_.size();
   }
  ```
- File `server.cpp`

  ```
   #include "server.h"
   #include <signal.h>
   #include <utility>

   using boost::system::error_code;

   Server::Server(const std::string& address, const std::string& port)
       : io_context_(1) // THREAD HINT: single threaded
       , connection_manager_()
   {
       // Register to handle the signals that indicate when the server should exit.
       // It is safe to register for the same signal multiple times in a program,
       // provided all registration for the specified signal is made through Asio.
       signals_.add(SIGINT);
       signals_.add(SIGTERM);
   #if defined(SIGQUIT)
       signals_.add(SIGQUIT);
   #endif // defined(SIGQUIT)

       do_await_signal();

       // Open the acceptor with the option to reuse the address (i.e. SO_REUSEADDR).
       tcp::resolver resolver(io_context_);
       tcp::endpoint endpoint = *resolver.resolve({address, port});
       acceptor_.open(endpoint.protocol());
       acceptor_.set_option(tcp::acceptor::reuse_address(true));
       acceptor_.bind(endpoint);
       acceptor_.listen();

       do_accept();
   }

   void Server::run() {
       // The io_service::run() call will block until all asynchronous operations
       // have finished. While the server is running, there is always at least one
       // asynchronous operation outstanding: the asynchronous accept call waiting
       // for new incoming connections.
       io_context_.run();
   }

   void Server::do_accept() {
       // separate strand for each connection - just in case you ever add threads
       acceptor_.async_accept(
           make_strand(io_context_), [this](error_code ec, tcp::socket sock) {
               if (!ec) {
                   connection_manager_.register_and_start(
                       std::make_shared<Connection>(std::move(sock),
                                                    connection_manager_));
                   do_accept();
               }
           });
   }

   void Server::do_await_signal() {
       signals_.async_wait([this](error_code /*ec*/, int /*signo*/) {
           // handler on the strand_ because of the executor on signals_

           // The server is stopped by cancelling all outstanding asynchronous
           // operations. Once all operations have finished the io_service::run()
           // call will exit.
           acceptor_.cancel();
           connection_manager_.stop_all();
       });
   }

   bool Server::deliver(const std::string& buffer) {
       if (io_context_.stopped()) {
           return false;
       }
       post(io_context_,
            [this, buffer] { connection_manager_.broadcast(std::move(buffer)); });
       return true;
   }
  ```
- File `test.cpp`

  ```
   #include "server.h"

   int main() {
       Server s("127.0.0.1", "8989");

       std::thread yolo([&s] {
           using namespace std::literals;
           int i = 1;

           do {
               std::this_thread::sleep_for(5s);
           } while (s.deliver("HEARTBEAT DEMO " + std::to_string(i++)));
       });

       s.run();

       yolo.join();
   }
  ```

Comment: In case it helps with reviewing the changes: https://github.com/sehe/stackoverflow-q71744762/commits/master

Comment: I should have probably mentioned that the application is multithreaded. There are 4 threads that call Server::deliver with their own data when they produce. However, as I had a single io_service, I thought that I would not need strands. I will edit the question with this information.

Comment: I was using getNativeHandle() just for logging purposes which I excluded in the question.

Comment: thanks for the codes. It seems to be working so far. I had to upgrade my boost version from 1.53 to 1.76 though since post() function was not available in 1.53.

Comment: Just pushed another simplification removing the `ConnectionManager` reverse dependency in the first place (since `weak_ptr` it adds no value anymore): https://github.com/sehe/stackoverflow-q71744762/commit/b8b7280be9b448952880d0aa3b1a4e50cfb4411a

Comment: I have one more question: Why did we supply 1 as the hint for io_context constructor? As far as I understand, that is the number of threads from which dispatched handlers will be invoked. Would not it be bad if 1000 clients tried to connect to the server **at the same time**, with just 1 dispatcher thread is serving them.

Comment: That would usually be peanuts. The trick is to not do blocking work on IO handlers (uses queues and a worker thread pool to decouple that kind of work). Look up "10k servers" [e.g. popularized by NodeJs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34855352/85371).

Comment: To answer the direct question "why did we supply 1 as the hint" - we did because the hint **matches our scenario**. (It gives the executors the capability to optimize. Specifically, it may allow a strand provider to eliminate any locking exclusion. It would be sad to pay for synchronization overhead when it's not required)

Comment: By the way, I appreciate when people spot the details. Thanks for asking!

Comment: By saying "it matches to our scenario", I guess you are implying that since we have just a single thread that executes io_context::run, it is suitable for us. Right? Btw I did not quite understand what you mean by "uses queues and a worker thread pool to decouple that kind of work". Who uses this? Is it the underlying implementation of ASIO, or should I implement this system? "IO handlers" are basically "completion handler"s, right? I aim to implement a scalable (and also robust of course) server, and I am not sure how scalable a server would be with just a single io_context.

Comment: It was a typo.  I meant to say "use queueus", not "uses queues". Sorry. So yes, that's a recommendation if you need long-running tasks in reponse to IO. IO handlers are completion handlers and any other handlers you post (or the library on your behalf). Again, you don't need to wonder how scalable a server can be with a single IO thread. This is (very) well-known territory. In practice it is extremely rare that you can saturate more than a single core with IO tasks and still do useful work in response. Did you read [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34855352/85371)?

Comment: Obviously it's possible to think of exceptional situations where you actually benefit from multiple IO threads - but it comes at the price of complicating and often introduces locking, hurting efficiency [realistically, if it matters, you'll be in real-time OS, thread priority, thread affinity and cache optimization land anyways).

Comment: The most compelling reason to use multi-threaded IO is because you can be "lazy" in the design and not distinguish work from IO (effectively running the IO on your work pool). However in my professional experience this "easy mode" always comes back to bite later (e.g. when you need to handle stress load, error conditions, or need to guarantee latency regardless of system load. All of these are /hard/ without the IO/work separation.)

Comment: I have read your link. I have also found http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html useful.

Comment: Thanks again for your code. It works very good most of the time, however there are some cases in which broadcasting will not send a message to every connected client (will send to a subset of them). Of course, this might be an issue on the client side (even though might be off-topic but I am using Qt sockets on client side), and I will check on it as well. Do you think the server that you implemented here is prone to such bug? To my knowledge, I cannot see any problem with it related to this.

Comment: Use logging or wireshark/ethercap/ethereal/tcpdump to inspect the actual traffic to debug this kind of thing. You may also wish to log construction/destruction of `connection` objects with the remote endpoint. Perhaps your client is getting disconnected some of the time?

Comment: It is possible that client is getting disconnected from time to time. Clients communicate with the server via VPN, and it is a rather unstable connection.